# How can you merge two data frames on a column that both data frames have if the column d types are not the same?

Tags: python, data-science, computer-science

I have two dataframes with a column called "US Postal State Code" and I am trying to merge them together on that column into a new dataframe. The problem is that the column has an object dtype in the first dataframe and a int64 dtype in the second dataframe.

I tried to change the column with the object dtype to int64 using

```
    Enterprise3['US Postal State Code']=Enterprise3['US Postal State Code'].astype(int)
```

however I got an error that states

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AL'
```

Is there another way to change the dtypes so that they match and can be merged?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert one of the columns to the others datatype with a custom function:

```py
def convert_postal(p):
    if p == "AL":
        return 35045
    elif p = "OtherCodes":
        return other_codes_numerical_code

Enterprise3["US Postal State Code"] = Enterprise3["US Postal State Code"].map(convert_postal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dtype attribute on your dataframe to see what kinds of datatypes you have. Afterwards coerce them into the proper datatype. Your calculation does not work since some of your values have the foreign datatype.